# NHibernate child and parent have different key names?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm working with an existing database and can't change the schema.  Lets say we sell widgets.  Each order for widgets has an entry in the WidgetBase table with a key named uid. Now, the specific parameters needed for each widget in the order are contained in another table called WidgetParams.  WidgetParams has a column called TBuild that links to the uid column in the WidgetBase table.

How do I do the mapping in nHibernate when the key names are different?

Comment: What does your object model look like? are you using Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of the foreign key column on both sides (if mapping bi-directional)

Widget

```
HasMany<WidgetParams>(x => x.widgetParams)
    .KeyColumn("TBuild")
```

WidgetParams

```
References<Widget>(x => x.widget)
    .Column("TBuild")
```